# SQL Inner Join query like LEFT OUTER JOIN

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, inner-join, outer-join

I have a problem with sql inner join. My tables, columns, data types and table values at following image.

[image]

My working query is:

```
SELECT O.ORDER_ID, O.ORDER_DATE, O.QUANTITY, 
    P.PART_ID, P.PART_CODE, P.PART_NAME,
    C.CUST_ID, C.CUST_CODE, C.CUST_NAME
FROM (([dbo].[ORDER] O
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[CUSTOMER] C
    ON C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID)
LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[PART] P
    ON P.PART_ID = O.PART_ID
```

and it is returning that
[image]

so my question is, I want to write a query like second image but I should **use INNER JOIN** which will make left outer join's job. I wrote following query for this

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM [dbo].[ORDER] O 
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER C
    ON (C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID OR
        O.CUST_ID IS NULL)
```

but it doesn't return **LEFT OUTER JOIN** query result to me. How can I do this **without use** LEFT OUTER JOIN ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on the teacher's intent. If this is a language question, and not a logical operator question, use OUTER APPLY:

```
SELECT O.*, D.*
FROM [dbo].[ORDER] O 
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT *
    FROM [dbo].CUSTOMER C
    WHERE C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID
) D
```

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is: You cannot replace a left join with an inner join easily and keep the same functionality. (And why would you?)

A left outer join lets you join a second table, but keep the first table's record even when *no match* in the second table exists. An inner join on the other hand limits your first table's records such that *only matches* are shown.

```
INNER JOIN CUSTOMER C ON (C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID OR O.CUST_ID IS NULL)
```

Here you *partly join* table CUSTOMER. When the order table contains a customer, you join the according customer record to the order record. When the order table doesn't contain a customer, you join all customers to the order record.

Of course you could always trick. Add a null record on the fly:

```
INNER JOIN 
(
  SELECT CUST_ID, CUST_CODE, CUST_NAME
  FROM CUSTOMER
  UNION ALL
  SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL
) C ON (C.CUST_ID = O.CUST_ID OR (C.CUST_ID IS NULL AND O.CUST_ID IS NULL))
```

But as said: Why would you do that instead of using the straight-forward way of using LEFT OUTER JOIN?

Comment: I know how left outer join works but my teacher said: "How can you do left outer join's job via inner join or another way. Don't use left outer join"

Comment: Hm, well, a strange task in my opinion. But you got your solution ;-) Another way, btw, to replace an outer join would be two selects and UNION: `select x.a, y.b from x join y on x.id=y.id UNION ALL select a, null from x where id is null`. Maybe this is what your teacher was looking for.